# How to group routes in vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

On my site I have a navigations with some categories and nested navigation anchors in them. How can I group this routes in vue-router? The best I've come up with is to place for each route a meta and then group by it.

Comment: You can use nested routes https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html

Answer (score 8):

I use like this (look that `component: { render: h => h('router-view') }`):

```js
      {
// =============================================================================
// MAIN LAYOUT ROUTES
// =============================================================================
        path: '',
        component: () => import('./layouts/main/Main.vue'),
        children: [
// =============================================================================
//    Routes
// =============================================================================
          {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue'),
          },
// =============================================================================
//    User Routes
// =============================================================================
          {
            path: '/user',
            name: 'user',
            component: { render: h => h('router-view') },
            children: [
              {
                path: 'list',
                name: 'user.list',
                component: () => import('./views/pages/User/List.vue'),
              },
            ]
          },

        ],
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is great and EXACTLY what I was looking for, and should probably be marked as the accepted answer. Would you mind explaining a little more in-depth what's going on with `component: { render: h => h('router-view') }`?  I added an excerpt from the vue docs and a link, but I'm still a little hazy on *exactly* what's  happening. Thanks again!

Comment: @KevinFoster its will render <router-view /> and the childrens will be renders on there.

Comment: Hey @Pablo Papalardo !  Thanks for your response - I see my edit with a reference was removed or not accepted, so maybe this is irrelevant - I was more looking for a little more explanation about why and how `render:  h => h(...) ` works, because although plugging in `router-view` is intuitive and makes perfect sense, how the call is structured, and why that works is a little fuzzy, and documentation is sparse. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is looking for vue 3, `h` is not being passed to the `render` function anymore, but it should be imported from the vue namespace
`import { h } from 'vue'`
`render: () => h('router-view')`
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/render-function-api.html#_3-x-syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is forked and fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewright/wsmx92bg/

You should know, that children routers opens inside parent template. That means you need to add additional `<router-view>` inside parent template.

The idea is that: children routers change some block, like part of parent content. Good way to use it - for subcategory menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested routes. In your routes file you can do something similar.

```
{
  path: '/category',
  name: 'category',
  component: Category,
  children: [
      {
         path: 'subcategory',
         name: 'subCategory',
         component: ChildComponent,
      },
      // other nested routes
  ]
},
```

Comment: This is nog meant to group routes. Rather than to nest components. These are different things

Comment: @sanders how so? and what's your solution?