# Vue transition failed when use group routes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, transition

I want use group route and the nested routes mount at top level, so I found the [issue1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1507)、[issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343260/5046887) and fix the problem.

But when I added the transition tag for the `<route-view>` the transition is not work correctly by using group route. 
 Here is the full code https://codepen.io/changemyminds/pen/ExmLdBM

You click `Home -> Profile` and `Profile -> Home` the transition work correctly, but when you click `User -> Role` and `Role -> User` the transition work failed and just flashing.

[image]

Some code snippet.

**Routes**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
    { path: '/prfile', name: 'Profile', component: Profile },
    { 
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'Admin',
      component: { render: (h) => h("router-view") },
      redirect: "/admin/user",
      children: [         
        { path: 'user', name: 'User', component: User },
        { path: 'role', name: 'Role', component: Role }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

**View**

```
  <div>
    <h1>Correct Transition</h1>    
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Home'}">
      <button>Home</button>
    </router-link>
   
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Profile'}">
      <button>Profile</button>
    </router-link>    
 
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Failed Transition</h1>   
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'User'}">
      <button>User</button>
    </router-link>

    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Role'}">
      <button>Role</button>
    </router-link> 
  </div>
  
  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </transition>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active for below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Seems the `v-leave-active` and `v-leave-to` is not working. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem because I lost the `key` on the parent `<router-view>`.

If I set key with `this.$route.path` the Vue virtual DOM will different and will trigger the transition again.

- View

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- same tag bypass... -->

  <transition name="slide-fade">
    <router-view :key="key"></router-view>
  </transition>
</div>
```

- Routes

```js
<!-- same routes bypass... -->

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  computed: {
    key() {
      return this.$route.path;
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/changemyminds/pen/XWRqyEr

Answer (score 0):

Since the Vue switch does not refresh the page, the hook function on the page will not be triggered. The official way to do this is to listen for changes in the route, but also by adding some parameters to the